# Difference in finding a number inside an unordered_map in C++ STL

Tags: c++, search, stl, unordered-map

In the case of unordered_map in C++, what is the main difference between:

1. if(map.find(n) != map.end())
2. if(map.count(n) > 0)
3. if(map[n] > 0)

Consider map is an unordered_map of type <int,int>.

Comment: 3) will create a new entry if not already. Read the documentation [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: This looks more like a homework question and you've made no effort to read the documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
if(map.find(n) != map.end())

if(map.count(n) > 0)
```

Are mostly equivalent. `map::count` will never return more than `1`.

This line:

```
if(map[n] > 0)
```

Loads the `value` associated with the key, `n` and compares if it's value is greater than zero. Not the same thing as the first two.  `map[n]` also has a side effect. If `n` is not already a key in the map, the map will create a new value ("default initialized" or "zero-init" value) for that key. Hence, it can increase the size of the map implicitly.